# My code hangs when trying to determine random number with probability

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a program that simulates game of tennis. Pretty straightforward to those who knows the rules, but here's my quick recap: for each game player must score 4 points and, if he wasn't two points ahead, players continue to play until one of them scores 2 or more than opponent to win a game. Same rules for winning a set - needs to be 2 more than opponent. Game ends after X amount of sets which are inputted by the user.

Pretty straightforward, but I also implemented variable which determines player A skill. For example, if player skill is more than 60, in theory he has bigger chance of winning a game.

So here is my code. Problem with it is that, if I set variable of `numberOfSets` to 10 and variable of `playerSkill` to anything more than 55 or less than 45, program hangs, CPU usage is going up(not by much, I only saw small spike to about 15%) and there seems to be nothing I can do other than stopping the program. If I set variable of `numberOfSets` to something low like 1 or 2, program seems to behave normally, even with stupid values of `playerSkill` like 1 or 99. I am fairly new to programming so there is definitely something I omitted, which may be obvious, or something really stupid I did and shouldn't have.

```
    int playerAGamesWon = 0;
    int playerBGamesWon = 0;
    int playerSkill = 50;
    int numberOfSets = 10;
    int numberOfGames = 6;
    int numberOfPoints = 4;


    void SimulateTennis()
    {
        txtData.Text = "Simulating game of tennis"+Environment.NewLine;
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSets; i++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                calculatePlayerPoints(rand);
                if (playerAGamesWon >= numberOfGames || playerBGamesWon >= numberOfGames)
                {
                    if (playerAGamesWon - playerBGamesWon >= 2)
                    {
                        playerASetWon++;
                        txtData.Text += "Player A won the Set with " + playerAGamesWon + " games to " + playerBGamesWon + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                        playerAGamesWon = 0;
                        playerBGamesWon = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (playerBGamesWon - playerAGamesWon >= 2)
                    {
                        playerBSetWon++;
                        txtData.Text += "Player B won the Set with "+ playerBGamesWon + " games to " + playerAGamesWon + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                        playerAGamesWon = 0;
                        playerBGamesWon = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void calculatePlayerPoints(Random rand)
    {
        int apoints = 0;
        int bpoints = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int prob = rand.Next(100);
            if (prob <= playerSkill)
            {
                apoints++;
            }
            else
            {
                bpoints++;
            }
            if (apoints >= numberOfPoints)
            {
                if (apoints - bpoints >= 2)
                {
                    playerAGamesWon++;
                    updateScoreText(apoints, bpoints);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //else if statement of (bpoints >= numberOfPoints) was unreachable when if statement of (apoints >= numberOfPoints) was true
            //I should use if statement
            //else if (bpoints >= numberOfPoints)
            if (bpoints >= numberOfPoints)
            {
                if (bpoints - apoints >= 2)
                {
                    playerBGamesWon++;
                    updateScoreText(apoints, bpoints);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn [to debug your own code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) to at least find out what the problem is.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I'm not going to try and debug this code for you, that's your job. However, you have a `while(true)` loop here, it's almost certainly getting stuck inside there.

Comment: Problem is, debugger showing nothing. Program hangs, Visual studio thinks it's working properly. Quick discovery though - any value above 50 works, smaller values below 50, like 49 or 48 are working, but anything less than causes the program to hang, I made a quick video showing how it behaves: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCORPpLIiGg)

Comment: Thank you guys for your time and links. If I find the solution I'll post an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter an infinite loop in the `calculatePlayerPoints` method. If the result of comparing `apoints` and numberOfPoints is `true`, but the condition `if (apoints - bpoints> = 2)` is `false`, then the comparison of `bpoints` and `numberOfPoints` will not occur. You must remove `else` in `else if (bpoints> = numberOfPoints)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. So to summarize, If one "if" statement is triggered, I can't continue to "else if" statement, I have to use another "if". My error caused an infite loop.